# Как реализовать перебор списка

Tags: python

Есть задачка. Как реализовать. Не могу написать 3 пункт.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    driver.get("https://parsinger.ru/selenium/5/5.html")
link = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'check')
numbers = [1,2,3,4,8,9,11,12,13,14,15]

for res in link:
    a = res.get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял в переменной "а" хранятся значения. То есть нужно через цикл сравнить переменную "а" с содержимым numbers.

if a in numbers:
...

Comment: А как после нажать на нужную галочку на сайте?

Comment: if a in number:
            click()
Не знаю как кликать нужно через селениум, но, суть в том, что если условие верно, то кликнуть нужно туда-то

Comment: Тут знают https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/click-element-method-selenium-python/

Answer (score 0):

Все невероятнейшим образом просто. Вам нужно отфильтровать полученный список со всеми  "check" объектами. Для этого в python  существует специальная функция ***filter()***, в которую сначала подается правило фильтрации(в Вашем случае значение ***value*** у элемента должно быть в заданном списке), а вторым аргументом сам список, который нужно отфильтровать. По полученному результату Вы пробегаетесь с помощью цикла ***for*** и просто вызываете метод ***.click()***

Первая попавшаяся ссылка на информацию про filter:
https://pythonru.com/uroki/funkcija-filter-dlja-nachinajushhih

***P.S.** ради интереса я решил эту задачу, и у меня все получилось, но это все-таки задача, поэтому решение не буду скидывать. Тем более, на сколько я знаю, это не в правилах платформы.*

Comment: Можно хоть часть кода для понимания?